# Mac App | Code Signed | distribution Not through Mac App store

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign, dmg, code-signing-certificate

Our Application will not be distributed via mac app store initially, it will be through DMG File,

Well in that case also, should it be signed / certified application ?

I tried in one of the test machine, its showing warning, this Application is downloaded from internet , so you are not allow to run, how to get rid of this,

if i make app signed, will it solved this problem, or any other procedure is there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should sign your app, even if you are not submitting it to the App Store.  See the [Developer ID and Gatekeeper guide](https://developer.apple.com/resources/developer-id/) for how to do this.  Yes, this is why you are seeing the warning.

By default, `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` is set to allow applications from `Mac App Store and identified developers`.  By signing your app, you are an `identified developer`.  Setting it to `Anywhere` would allow the user to install an unsigned app (as well as make them more vulnerable to malware, viruses, etc.)